# Zend Framework date without hours minutes and seconds

Tags: zend-framework

Anybody can help me to get date formated with Zend framework

**What I do is:**

```
<?php echo new Zend_Date(2010-05-23, false, 'en');?>
```

**Result I get is**: May 22, 2010 12:00:00 AM

**I what I need is:** May 22, 2010

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [string formatting options and constants](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html):

```
// Using the strings for reading the format:
$date = new Zend_Date('2010-05-23', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
// Using the constants for format:
echo $date->toString(Zend_Date::MONTH_NAME." ".Zend_Date::DAY_SHORT.", ".Zend_Date::YEAR);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks that is cool I think :) But is there any way to handle that with locale? I mean to get string formated by locale? Now I got this: "mayo 23, 2010" for Spanish locale and it is not correct :(

Comment: @Trimm - Yes - the second argument to `toString()` can be a locale... try passing in 'en'

Comment: Perfect! Thats it :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The date is returned as ISO standard date, unless you specify a format, as mentioned on the Zend Framework documentation on [`Zend_Data`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.phpformats)

A much easier solution would be:

```
 <?php echo date("F d, Y", strtotime(new Zend_Date(2010-05-23, false, 'en')));?>
```

Comment: That gave me: Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in /Users/...

Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: `->getTimestamp()` on the `Zend_Date` should give you the long you can pass to `date()`

Comment: sorry, I forgot that it was not returning it as an Epoch. Updated, should work.

Answer (score 0):

Only with Zend_Date...

```
$dateArray = array('year' => 2010, 'month' => 5, 'day' => 23);
$now = new Zend_Date($dateArray);
$date = $now->toString(Zend_Date::MONTH_NAME . ' ' . Zend_Date::DAY . ', ' . Zend_Date::YEAR);
```